# Design firebase DB for filtering

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use Firebase and AngularFire4 in a web application. The model is relatively simple, but I am having troubles in finding the right way to design it.

I have two collections: `places` and `countries` like the following:

**Places**

```
 "places" : {
   "-Kjx7NhHnyZNIZbxvzx4" : {   
      "name" : "Dereck beer",
      "type" : "Bar"   
      "location" : {
          "cityName" : "Kagoshima",
          "country" : {
             "code" : "JP",
             "id" : 110,
             "name" : "Japan"
             },
             "streetName" : "892-0842 Higashisen"
        },
       "modifiedOn": 121211321321
     }
    //... More data here...
  }
```

**Countries**

```
"countries" : {
   "110" : {
           "code" : "JP",
           "id" : 110,
           "name" : "Japan"
          }
  }
```

At the moment in the web application I display the list of places and I can navigate to the detail view of each place. I can also display the countries where the places belong to (I create a new entry in countries collection, if not existing already, when a new place is created/updated).

However I would like to filter the places by some properties, like by type for instance. I tried with the following query, from [AngularFire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md), but it does not work:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
     var query = {
        orderByChild: 'modifiedOn',
        equalTo: { 
           value: 'Bar', 
           key: 'type' }
        };

         this.db.list("/places", query).subscribe( data => {
              //All places are returned, and not only the one of type = "Bar"
         });
 }
```

If possible, I would like to avoid [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077939/angularfire2-retrieve-double-nested-object-by-property-value) and to replicate excessively my collections just for being able to query them.

Comment: It would be nice to have a reason of negative votes, so that people can avoid mistakes (if any) for the next question. Sometimes questions that might seem "obvious" to some, can be not so obvious when faced directly and details get simply "hidden" while developing a solution.

Comment: yeah.. downvote without comment is rude, especially if the person who asking is over one thousand reputations

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
var query = {
    orderByChild: 'type',
    equalTo: 'Bar'
};
```

`orderByChild` and `equalTo` is a pair in firebase, it's different from sql query

Comment: I will give it a try thanks. Howver I would like to execute a query and sort by creationDate using: orderByChild: 'modifiedOn'. Using the optional key/value properties should be valid, according to angularFire docs.

Comment: Hi Faruk, I tried but I still get back the whole results (not filtered) and I would like to sort the data on server side, rather on client side. I will have to dig deeper in the documentation I guess.